# sonar issue: Extract this nested try block into a separate method

Tags: java

**java**
As you can see in the below code in sonar its give the "Extract this nested try block into a separate method". I am not understand how to resolve this issue please anyone can help.

```
Vector<?> allFiles = channelSftp.ls(remoteDirectory + "/");
                    for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.size(); i++) {
                        LsEntry le = (LsEntry) allFiles.get(i);
                        String strName = le.getFilename();
                        if (strName.startsWith(prefixFileName)) {
                            fileName = strName;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    remoteFilePath = remoteDirectory + fileName;
                    localFilePath = localDirectory + fileName;
                    try {
                        channelSftp.get(remoteFilePath, localFilePath);
                    } catch (SftpException e) {
                        migrationRunBatchRepository.updateBatchStatus(migrationRunBatch.getMromRunSeqId(),
                                migrationRunBatch.getMromBatchSeqId(), MROMConstants.MIGRATION_RUN_STATUS_RETRY,
                                MROMConstants.MC_NM1TRIGGER_JOB_USER);
                        throw new FileTransferException("File Not Found in Remote Directory", e);
                    }
                    channelSftp.rm(remoteFilePath);
                    channelSftp.exit();
                    session.disconnect();

                    int count = migrationRunRepository.getCmRunIdCount(cmrunid);
                    if (acceptDuplicateCmRunId || count > 0) {
                        Long mromRunSeqId = (long) chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters()
                                .get(MROMConstants.MROM_RUN_SEQ_ID);
```

Comment: The code you posted does not show a nested try block. Is the issue that Sonar gives you the error despite there not being a try-catch inside a try-catch? Does the error go away if you move your try-catch into a separate method?